# how to get all logs from a block in Ethereum with infura

Tags: filter, ethereum, web3js

I would like to get all logs from a given block in Ethereum with one call. I know we can get transaction receipt one by one, then from each receipt, we can get its logs. But this seems not efficient.

From [infura documentation](https://infura.io/docs/ethereum/json-rpc/eth_getLogs), we can use eth_getLogs method to returns an array of all logs matching a given filter object, such as address, block (from and to), topic, blockhash. I have tried to use the blockhash filter alone (shown as follows) and it returns me a list of logs:

```
curl https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/project-id \
    -X POST \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -d '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_getLogs","params":[{"blockHash": "0xf05a7ef9ca8df22301939cfb144c9ec0795fc0868ec0bab9e08b078da5bb5838"}],"id":1}'
```

However, when I tried to code it in my program, I can not find a way to create a ETH filter with a blockHash. I need to create a request ETH filter in this way, EthFilter(DefaultBlockParameter fromBlock, DefaultBlockParameter toBlock, List address). Does anyone know how to create a EthFilter with a blockHash?

I have been tested with this, trying to get all logs in the latest blcok,

```
org.web3j.protocol.core.methods.request.EthFilter filter = new org.web3j.protocol.core.methods.request.EthFilter(DefaultBlockParameterName.LATEST, DefaultBlockParameterName.LATEST, "");
EthLog ethLog = getEthereumClient().ethGetLogs(filter).send();
```

but the returned ethLog has an error msg, "data types must start with 0x". It seems that I have to give a specific contract address there, but that is not what I want. I want to get all logs from a block.

Thank you

Comment: Hey @Ming Wu did you find any solution?